# Optimizing repeated function calls

Tags: evaluation, mathematical-optimization, symbols, memoization

Easiest way to keep my library nice, is to naively call some functions many times with same parameters. Doing so prevents from zoo of (library-)global variables and complicated initialisation functions. I would expect Mathematica to optimise somehow functions calls with same parameters, but it does not appear to do that.

Fallowing example is ran on Mathematica 9:

```
rands = Array[Random[] &, {2500, 2500}];
Timing[Inverse[rands];]
Timing[Inverse[rands];]
Timing[Inverse[rands];]
Timing[Inverse[rands];]
```

Output:

```
{0.687500, Null}
{0.687500, Null}
{0.687500, Null}
{0.687500, Null}
```

Is there a way to make Mathematica optimise revaluation with same parameters? What kind of nice workaround would you recommend?

**EDIT**
As I learned, the keyword I needed was *memoization*. I found [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25150/2036) very useful. Thanks!

Comment: Search this site for `Memoization`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function like this

```
myInverse[x_]:= myInverse[x]=Inverse[x]
```

I get:

```
In[8]:= rands = Array[Random[] &, {2500, 2500}];

In[9]:= Timing[Inverse[rands];]
Timing[Inverse[rands];]
Timing[Inverse[rands];]

Out[9]= {6.292720, Null}
Out[10]= {5.771016, Null}
Out[11]= {5.534804, Null}

In[12]:= Timing[myInverse[rands];]
Timing[myInverse[rands];]
Timing[myInverse[rands];]

Out[12]= {5.842785, Null}
Out[13]= {0.000015, Null}
Out[14]= {4.\[CenterDot]10^-6, Null}
```